# Java summing recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am given an array of integers, and trying to define a recursive method sum(int[] A,int s, int e) to calculate the sum of array A, where s and e are starting index and ending index. I want to test it with a given array int[] A= {3,5,8,9,10}.

I am confused on how to do this but here is what I have so far (I am even a little confused on the code here because my buddy helped me write it, a little explanation would help a lot!):

```
public static int sum(int[]A,int s,int e) {
   if (s==e)
      return A[e];
else
   return A[5] + sum(A,s+1,e);
```

Comment: Why to use recursive calls in such algorithms?? It's bad approach.

Comment: how do you call this method?

Comment: There's a mistake in the last line; it should be `return A[s] ...` not `return A[5] ...`. Other than that, what exactly are you confused about?

Comment: @StanislavMamontov, the answer is almost certainly "to learn about recursion."

Comment: @pamphlet One of the biggest mistakes people make with recursion, is using it when it's completely unnecessary. The tutor, or whoever is teaching them, should use an example fit for recursion, so they can see *why* it's so useful it it's context.

Comment: @StanislavMamontov Yes, there are other non-recursive methods of calculating the result. However, this also seems like a relatively simple and easy to grasp example of what recursion is all about, so makes a decent introductory problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in @KlasLindbäck's answer, the 5 should be an s.

```
public static int sum(int[]A,int s,int e) {
   if (s==e)
      return A[e];
else
   return A[s] + sum(A,s+1,e);
```

To provide an explanation:

Firstly, to call this method:

```
int theSum = sum(myArray, 0, myArray.length-1);
```

I'll run through this for you {3,5,8,9,10} array.

```
sum(A, 0, 4):
return A[0] + sum(A, 1, 4)   //3 + sum(A, 1, 4)

sum(A, 1, 4):
return A[1] + sum(A, 2, 4)   //5 + sum(A, 2, 4)

sum(A, 2, 4):
return A[2] + sum(A, 3, 4)   //8 + sum(A, 3, 4)

sum(A, 3, 4):
return A[3] + sum(A, 4, 4)   //9 + sum(A, 4, 4)

sum(A, 4, 4):
return A[4]                  //10

Now, we know that sum(A, 4, 4) is 10, so therefore sum(A, 3, 4) is 9 + 10 = 19.
Now, we know that sum(A, 3, 4) is 19, so therefore sum(A, 2, 4) is 8 + 19 = 27.
Now, we know that sum(A, 2, 4) is 27, so therefore sum(A, 1, 4) is 5 + 27 = 32.
Now, we know that sum(A, 1, 4) is 32, so therefore sum(A, 0, 4) is 3 + 32 = 35.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missread one character. The `5` should be an `s` on the return line:

```
return A[s] + sum(A,s+1,e);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  package com.TTC.Tryfon.AbdulRahman;

public class Doing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] z={3,5,8,9,10};
        System.out.println(sum(z,0));   
    }

    public static int sum(int [] a,int index){
        if(index<a.length){
            return a[index]+sum(a,index+1); 
        }
        return 0;   
    }

}
```

The above program will produce the following result:

```
35
```

In order to understand the program lets execute this part:

```
if(index<a.length){
    return a[index]+sum(a,index+1); 
}
```

index start as 0, and a.length=5:

```
if(0<5){
    return a[0]+sum(a,0+1);
    // this means return 3+sum(a,1);    
}

if(1<5){
    return a[1]+sum(a,1+1);
    // this means return 5+sum(a,2);    
}

if(2<5){
    return a[2]+sum(a,2+1);
    // this means return 8+sum(a,3);    
}
if(3<5){
    return a[3]+sum(a,3+1);
    // this means return 9+sum(a,4);    
}
if(4<5){
    return a[4]+sum(a,4+1);
    // this means return 10+sum(a,5);   
}
if(5<5){
    // 5 is not smaller than 5, so it will return 0;
    }
return 0;
```

since there is no more function call, we must replace the returned number by the function call:

```
10+0
9+10
8+18
5+27
3+32 =35
```

This is my first explanation ever, I hope it is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the stop condition within the recursive call:

```
public static int sum(int[]A,int s,int e) {
     return A[s] + (s == e) ? 0 : sum(A, s+1, e);
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can. But saying "You can also do this" and throwing in operators they've likely not seen before, without explaining what it is and how it works, seems slightly ridiculous when they've said they don't really understand what's going on in the more readable version as it is.